# django model optimization, fields applicable on two Models

Tags: django, django-models

I question myself on how to create my models well.

I have `Project` Model which contains multiple `Control` (and each `Control` is applicable on multiple `Project`). But each `Control` got specific attributes for the `Project`

I mean, a Project can have 10 Controls, and each control

- Applicable can be "Applicable" or "Not Applicable"
- Status can be "Not Planned", "Planned", "Done"

So I made this :

```
class Project(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    code = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField("code", null=True, blank=True)
    description = models.TextField(default="")

class Control(models.Model):
    control_description = models.TextField()
```

and a third Model for the links between Project / Control / Others

```
class ProjectControl(models.Model):
    APPLICABLE_CHOICES = (
        ("A","Applicable"),
        ("NA","Not Applicable"),
    )
    STATUS_CHOICES = (
        ("D","Done"),
        ("NP", "Not Planned"),
        ("P", "Planned")
    )
    project = models.ForeignKey('Project', verbose_name="Project", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    control = models.ForeignKey('Control', verbose_name="Controle", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    applicable = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True, choices=APPLICABLE_CHOICES)
    status = models.CharField(max_length=100, choices=STATUS_CHOICES)
```

Is there a better (or more conventional) way to do this ?

I'm just facing an issue when using API, if I want all applicable controls of a project, I have to parse the whole ProjectControl Table, and I think, if the project goes big, performance issues.

I tried this to resolve the issue by using M2M Field:

```
class Project(models.Model):
    controls = models.ManyToManyField("Control", related_name="controls", default="", null=True, blank=True)
```

But I don't know how to deal with the applicable / status choices for each control/project

Thanks Guys.

Comment: Why do you need to parse the entire `ProjectControl` table. Django will make an index by default on all `ForeignKey`s, so that means it will normally take on;ly time in the number of `ProjectControl`s *related* to that `Project` if you look it up.

Comment: I don't have a ProjectControl Foreign key for my Project. Maybe I should create a M2M between Project <-> ProjectControl, and just populate the M2M Field by creating ProjectControl Entry and adding it to Project ?

Comment: but that is again, not necessary, you have a `project = models.ForeignKey(...)`, so Django will construct an *index* at the database level that can retrieve efficiently all `ProjectControl` records related to a given `Project`.

Comment: Ohh I think I got It :) Due to the foreignkey in ProjectControl, I can (without adding anything in Project) call all ProjectControls from the Project. Like : Project.ProjectControl.all() ?

Comment: you can obtain all related `PorjectControl` objects with `myproject.projectcontrol_set.all()` yes. (where `myproject` is a `Project` object).

Comment: The other issue I had was about getting the value in Django DRF, I added `'projectcontrol_set'` to my `fields` and got the values ! Thanks !